# JAX/WS wsgen is not generating

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wsgen

I have a problem like this ; Could you please help me if you know the reason?

I m trying to generate jaxb classes for input and out types using wsgen command line utility.

[image: error]  [image: Eclipse]

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and not just a screen capture.

Comment: sorry I added new one maybe now it is better.

Answer (score 3):

The print screen you posted (and @home's comment is spot on - you should add the stacktrace not a print screen) tells you the problem.

> @javax.jws.WebService annotated classes that do not belong to a package must have the @javax.jws.WebService.targetNamespace element.

You don't specify a target namespace and wsgen can't infer one because you classes are in the default package. Having classes in the default package is a frown upon practice. Put your classes under a package and try again or have the [WebService.targetNamespace element](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jws/WebService.html#targetNamespace%28%29) set up which also gives you more control on what the tool generates.

Answer (score 0):

@javax.jws.WebService the annotated classe who implements Web Service Business interface, must have a no-argument constructor otherwise  wsGen tool gets such error.
Reference: [Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html)